# How is MSE defined for Image comparison?

Tags: machine-learning

I am building a convolution autoencoder that uses MSE as its error function. How is MSE defined for images? If the image is presented in simple matrix form, is MSE simply the square of the difference of individual determinants? Or is it the square of the determinant of the difference of the matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no determinant involved when calculating MSE. MSE stands for Mean Squared Error, and it is simply a sum over squares of the differences per each single pixel in your matrix. In other words - cost is model agnostic, MSE is defined in exactly the same way whether you use conv-autoencoder, simple autoencoder or simple MLP.

Comment: "cost is model agnostic" I understood this, but was wondering about the exact formula in case of matrices. Got that cleared. Thanks.